# Python raises os error when trying to rename an existing file

Tags: python

Sorry about asking such basic issue, but I am pretty lost now. The following code raises an os error (No such file or directory) kind of randomly, even when the file exists.

```
try:
    os.rename(ruta,ruta[:-6])
except Exception as e:
    print "No pude renombrar la ruta "+ruta+" como "+ruta[:-6]
    print e
```

An example of run:

```
arivacoba@computer:~/Desarrollo/Medea$ ./nmsorter0.py 
    ---Status messages not relevant to the issue---
    ---Some status messages about the successful renaming of most directories---
No pude renombrar la ruta /home/arivacoba/Desarrollo/Organizar/Audio/Jazz diverso/2015 VA - Jazz Lounge Classics Vol.2/CD 1.AUDIO como /home/arivacoba/Desarrollo/Organizar/Audio/Jazz diverso/2015 VA - Jazz Lounge Classics Vol.2/CD 1
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
No pude renombrar la ruta /home/arivacoba/Desarrollo/Organizar/Audio/Jazz diverso/2015 VA - Jazz Lounge Classics Vol.2/CD 2.AUDIO como /home/arivacoba/Desarrollo/Organizar/Audio/Jazz diverso/2015 VA - Jazz Lounge Classics Vol.2/CD 2
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

In this example, I have verified the existance of the files. More so, I am able to rename the files from python:

```
arivacoba@computer:~/Desarrollo/Medea$ python
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> ruta='/home/arivacoba/Desarrollo/Organizar/Audio/Jazz diverso/2015 VA - Jazz Lounge Classics Vol.2/CD 2.AUDIO'
>>> os.rename(ruta,ruta[:-6])
>>> os.rename('/home/arivacoba/Desarrollo/Organizar/Audio/Jazz diverso/2015 VA - Jazz Lounge Classics Vol.2/CD 1.AUDIO','/home/arivacoba/Desarrollo/Organizar/Audio/Jazz diverso/2015 VA - Jazz Lounge Classics Vol.2/CD 1')
>>>
arivacoba@computer:~/Desarrollo/Medea$ ls ../Organizar/Audio/Jazz\ diverso/2015\ VA\ -\ Jazz\ Lounge\ Classics\ Vol.2/
CD 1    CD 2     front.jpg     index.mfo
arivacoba@computer:~/Desarrollo/Medea$
```

As said before, it happens kind of randomly; I pass chunks of a huge corpus to the aplication in order to process it, but I have observed:

1. If the error is raised in a batch, it will happen always in the
   same directories.
2. If the same errored directory is tried in another batch, i.e. with other set of data, it may or may not raise the error; most probably will work ok.
3. It never ever throws a sole error. If a batch presents this error,
   there will be at least 2 errored directories.
4. It will behave as described in different platforms: I've tried it running on centos 7, debian Jessie and xUbuntu 18.04

I already have a workaround, however it kinda despairs me that I am not able to see what is wrong in such simple code.

Workaround

```
 os.system (("mv '%s' '%s'") % (ruta,ruta[:-6]))
```

Works just fine, although is kinda slow.

UPDATE: Inserting a sleep after renaming works every time, albeit slowly :S
Here is the code for the whole cycle, where I have no idea what may be causing this... race condition?

```
for cada in _restDir:
    ruta = os.path.realpath(cada)
    ddir = 'DIR'+cada[-5:]
    ruta = ruta.replace(DIRBASE,(eval(ddir))

    try:
        os.rename(ruta,ruta[:-6])
    except Exception as e:
        print "No pude renombrar la ruta "+ruta+" como "+ruta[:-6]
        print e
    sleep (0.1)
```

UPDATE: Almost two years later. We are updating the whole thing, and it works flawlessly in python 3.6. Out of curiosity, I installed 2.7.18 and 2.7.17, and tested in other machines (2.7.16 on Ubuntu, and 2.7.11 on centos). Well, it works as intended in >= 2.7.17, breaks as frequently/randomly with 2.7.11.
2.7.16 on Ubuntu is kinda funny. It still breaks randomly, but only when the filename contains more than 8 white spaces! Ask me how we discovered that. :D

Comment: Is this filesystem mounted over NFS or so?  Could any other process be concurrently manipulating it (perhaps via symlinks)?

Comment: Well errno `2` file not found is fairly obvious: either the source file or the target directory into the file is to be renamed does not exist. Common problems would be typo, including the less obvious possibilities like characters with similar appearance at the first glance or an extra leading/trailing (white)space in either source or target. For the latter case to make catch that in console output, it's a good idea to make sure that printed variable values are quoted or otherwise clearly delimited.

Comment: @davis-herring, the production version will eventually access parts of the corpus via NFS and SAMBA. Currently, the test are being made in a local fs, and have already checked for concurrency issues.

Comment: @Ondrej-k Since the path and filenames are obtained automatically, I thought that perhaps somewhere there were some artifacts in translation between character encoding; so I have already compared the path string byte to byte, with no positive results, as they are the same.